# Problema com biblioteca python - selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

Olá, estou querendo aprender um pouco mais de interações WEB com algumas linguagens. A linguagem que estou focando é o Python(já tenho algum conhecimento). Estou usando a biblioteca Selenium - webdriver e quero apenas fazer com que um script meu clique em um botão de um respectivo site.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://outlook.live.com/owa/')
browser.maximize_window()

btn = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header/div/aside/div/nav/ul/li[2]/a')
btn.click()
browser.quit()
```

Esse simples código está dando esses problemas.

```
C:\pythonDocuments\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/pythonDocuments/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pythonDocuments\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Users\ffccs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\ffccs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/pythonDocuments/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "C:\pythonDocuments\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\pythonDocuments\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Infelizmente não foi má instalação da biblioteca, já instalei manualmente e instalei o pycharm para fazer a instalação por ele também e nada deu certo.
Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar baixar novamente o ChromeDriver que seja da mesma versão do seu navegador.

Para ver: tres pontos => ajuda => sobre o google chrome

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Então você tem várias opções:

- adicione-o ao `PATH` do seu sistema.
- coloque-o no mesmo diretório do seu script Python.
- especifique o local diretamente via caminho do executável:

  `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/caminho/para/chromedriver.exe')`

Answer (score 0):

Para usar lib selenium seja em python ou java requerer um web driver, esteja usando firefox,chrome ou qualquer navegador tem que baixar o driver correspondente ao navegador desejado.

Mas  si o navegador do teu pc estiver desatualizado saira um erro no console, indicando que teu navegador não segui a versão do driver baixado.

Tanto teu navegador de uso seja o chrome tem que estar atualizado com o driver baixado.Após realizar o download tem que indicar o caminho onde esta o teu web driver.

Se quer automatizar usando o chrome, seu navegador e o web driver tem que ser da mesma versão.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que vc conseguiu resolver com as dicas dos colegas acima. Olhando seu código, vc precisa dar uma melhorada nesse *locator*. O *xpath* da forma que está, pode gerar erro facilmente, caso tenha alguma alteração no caminho do elemento. Uma dica, é usar o *id* do elemento. Caso o *id* não esteja disponível, podes usar o *xpath* dessa forma:

```
seu_locator = (By.XPATH, "//h1[contains(@class, 'title2')])"
```